# Getting coordinates in matplotlib from saved image

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm looking for some general way to convert saved-image coordinates to matplotlib coordinates:

Let's take an example - here I create a simple bar chart and saving it as png image:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


y = [5, 6, 15, 22, 24, 10]
x = range(len(y))

plt.bar(x, y)

plt.savefig('test.png')
```

this results a PNG image like this:

[image: result]

Now I show this image in browser and user clicks on it somewhere her:

[image: click]

Now the problem - how to calculate that user click coordinates on image (f.e `left=300, top=400`) transforms to plot coordinates `x=2, y=15`

UPD: please keep in mind - this is more general question.. not the specific bars - currently my serverside software can generate wide range of plot types using seaborn library (heatmaps, historgrams, boxes, swarms etc). it works great and the only thing users want is to get data coordinates on clicks. Rewriting this all with Javascript charts engine could be very time consuming.

So the goal is - if we have image with 300dpi and coordinates x, y - how to transform it to plot coordinate system (with all the axis offsets and padding)

Comment: This looks more like a javascript question instead of python as python's job ends when the png is created. What you could do is to make the div of the picture the same size as the png and then try to get X and Y of the click inside the said div.

Comment: Can you ask the user to input the plot limits? If so, there are many online tools you can borrow ideas from, e.g.: https://automeris.io/WebPlotDigitizer/

Comment: reminds me of https://xkcd.com/2341/ :D